# What energy efficient options are there for small baking quantities?

Tags: baking

This morning felt like some scones and had to pre-heat my normal oven to 220C which takes like 15m - just to bake a very small batch of scones (literally 4) which took 12m.

I'm a energy conscious bachelor and wont be baking for large quantities often so was wondering what my options there are for quick small scale baking (literally, a handful of scones / mini bundt cake / a couple of pastries).

My microwave is rather dated, so I was wondering if I could get something like:

https://www.lg.com/za/microwaves/lg-MS5696HIT
or

https://www.lg.com/za/microwaves/lg-MH8265DIS
or

https://www.lg.com/za/microwaves/lg-MA3884VC

Much smaller loading area which should heat up quicker and inverter tech should also be more efficient, but can it bake? Or perhaps something else entirely I'm overlooking?

Comment: A good combination microwave does a good job (I have one at home and one in my camper van) but it loses so much more heat to the room than a well insulated oven that you might not save much overall.

Comment: Have you considered making larger batches?Hold of turning the oven until you can bake several dishes at once? Then you can freeze excess goods and consume at your own pace. This of course only works for freezable foods, and if you don't mind not eating warm right of the oven.

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of counter-top ovens on the market that fit the bill. They range from fairly simplistic, to feature-rich and quite good. The most basic would easily bake a few muffins.  These are not microwave ovens, but more like your home oven on a smaller scale.  Searching "countertop oven" will yield many results.

Comment: FWIW to people like me, a 'counter-top oven' is just another way of referring to a Toaster Oven.

Comment: Thanks - but wouldnt these be just as inefficient as the normal oven? After a bit more research, it would appear that I should be looking into Gas Convection Ovens...

Comment: Smaller oven, less space to heat, less time to heat = less time in use...potentially different source of energy.  So, just as efficient?  Nah....I doubt it, but it depends on the efficiency of your full size oven I guess.